# Adding Meta Data Columns To Stripe Data Report from `report_runs` API

Tags: curl, stripe-payments

## Short Description

I'm attempting to automate a report that we're manually generating from the Stripe WebUI. I can grab most of the columns were interested in but I haven't been able to figure out how to grab all of the potential columns we can get from the WebUI.

## Successful Example Request

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/reporting/report_runs \
  -u $STRIPE_TEST_API_KEY \
  -d report_type="exports.unified_payments" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="id" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Description" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Seller Message" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Created (UTC)" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Amount" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Amount Refunded" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Currency" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Converted Amount" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Converted Amount Refunded" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Fee" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Tax" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Converted Currency" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Status" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Statement Descriptor" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Customer ID" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Customer Description" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Customer Email" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Captured" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Card ID" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Invoice ID" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Transfer" \
```

## Columns I Want To Add

```
payment_metadata[Admin URL] 
 payment_metadata[Buyer ID] 
 payment_metadata[Discounts] 
 payment_metadata[Item Total] 
 payment_metadata[Order Number] 
 payment_metadata[Payment ID] 
 payment_metadata[Request ID] 
 payment_metadata[Shipping] 
 payment_metadata[Shipping Class] 
 payment_metadata[Store ID] 
 payment_metadata[Storenvy ID] 
 payment_metadata[Tax] 
 payment_metadata[require_zip_check] 
 payment_metadata[requires_zip_check]
```

## Isn't There Documentation For This?

If you put in an incorrect name you get a response with [this documentation endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/reporting/statements/report-types#schema-exports-unified-payments) which hilariously 404s. Which means I'm currently playing a game of guess and check. I'm hopeful that someone on the internet knows more then I do on this topic.

## Column Name Syntax I've Tried

```
% curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/reporting/report_runs \
  -u $STRIPE_TEST_API_KEY \
  -d report_type="exports.unified_payments" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Order Number (metadata)"
{
  "error": {
    "message": "The value for `parameters.columns` contains invalid column identifiers: \"Order Number (metadata)\". For the list of valid columns for exports.unified_payments, see https://stripe.com/docs/reporting/statements/report-types#schema-exports-unified-payments.",
    "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_wcjrHaKjFjbT7t?t=1670317430",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
% curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/reporting/report_runs \
  -u $STRIPE_TEST_API_KEY \
  -d report_type="exports.unified_payments" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Order Number"
{
  "error": {
    "message": "The value for `parameters.columns` contains invalid column identifiers: \"Order Number\". For the list of valid columns for exports.unified_payments, see https://stripe.com/docs/reporting/statements/report-types#schema-exports-unified-payments.",
    "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_ocr6WwyUMWSsoA?t=1670317446",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
% curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/reporting/report_runs \
  -u $STRIPE_TEST_API_KEY \
  -d report_type="exports.unified_payments" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="payment_metadata[Order Number]"
{
  "error": {
    "message": "The value for `parameters.columns` contains invalid column identifiers: \"payment_metadata[Order Number]\". For the list of valid columns for exports.unified_payments, see https://stripe.com/docs/reporting/statements/report-types#schema-exports-unified-payments.",
    "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_fbKu58dqgAweLw?t=1670317597",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
% curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/reporting/report_runs \
  -u $STRIPE_TEST_API_KEY \
  -d report_type="exports.unified_payments" \
  -d "parameters[columns][]"="Payment Metadata[Order Number]"
{
  "error": {
    "message": "The value for `parameters.columns` contains invalid column identifiers: \"Payment Metadata[Order Number]\". For the list of valid columns for exports.unified_payments, see https://stripe.com/docs/reporting/statements/report-types#schema-exports-unified-payments.",
    "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_r8fVXjcgwwipRv?t=1670317908",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax is `-d "parameters[columns][]"="payment_metadata[Order Number]"`

You get the error though because that type of report (`exports.unified_payments`) does not support that column. Only certain *itemized* reports (such as `balance_change_from_activity.itemized.2` or `balance_change_from_activity.itemized.3`) support those columns; see the column definitions on https://stripe.com/docs/reports/report-types

Comment: Hmmm, the problem when I look at the itemized reports is they don't have any columns like `Converted Amount`, or `Card ID` like you can get when you manually export payments. In fact, most of the itemized reports are missing most of the columns you can manually retrieve.

Comment: I got off a call with Stripe support a little while ago and it looks like this use case is not supported via the reports API. You have to use the Sigma product to produce these kinds of payment based reports.